# Unable to display value in an html field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working in a script editor within Sharepoint, trying to just grab two input field values and display the sum when I click a calculate button. I've been following a number of guides on here and can't find where I've gone wrong. Nothing displays in the result text box.

```
First number: <input type="text" name="input1"/>
Second number: <input type="text" name="input2"/><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="add_number();"/>
<input type="text" name="display"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function add_number() {
var first_number = document.getElementByID('input1').value;
var second_number=document.getElementByID('input2').value;
var result = parseInt(first_number) + parseInt(second_number);
document.getElementByID('display').value = result;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: You're close. You'll need to add `id='display'` to the input element.